# Add legend of whole numbers instead of gradient in matplotlib

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, legend-properties

I'd like to add a legend that is only whole numbers, i.e. 0,1,2,3...14, instead of the gradient color bar. Basically, I want the array values to have a unique color and label in the legend, so that you can clearly distinguish each value in the array.

[image: array plot of land area]

```
fileloc=os.path.join(basepath, infile)
data=np.loadtxt(fileloc)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.imshow(data)
plt.colorbar()
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, the data is given as an integer numpy array which results in an image with exactly N different colors.

To get a colormap with exactly N colors from the viridis colormap, use `plt.cm.get_cmap('viridis', N)`. This will result in a colorbar with exactly N regions.

To get ticks nicely in the center of each region, divide the space into 2N+1 pieces, and then take all the odd positions. (So, if there are 5 colors, the colorbar will go from 0 to 4, which would get 11 marks of which mark 0 is skipped and marks 1, 3, 5, 7 and 9 are used). Next to each tick a label with the number can be placed.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4))

# create some random test data
data = np.random.normal(0, 0.05, size=(150, 150)).cumsum(axis=0).cumsum(axis=1)
data = data.astype(np.int)  # convert to integers
data -= data.min()  # let the numbers start at zero

num_colors = data.max() + 1
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('viridis', num_colors)
plt.imshow(data, cmap=cmap)
cbar = plt.colorbar(ticks=np.linspace(0, num_colors - 1, num_colors * 2 + 1)[1::2])
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(range(num_colors))

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap as follows:

```
custom_cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['purple','blue','green','yellow']) #... and so on until you have 15 colours specified
```

Then just pass that as the cmap argument to imshow and colorbar:

```
plt.imshow(data, cmap=custom_cmap)
plt.colorbar(cmap=custom_cmap)
```

Comment: `plt.colorbar` does not have a `cmap` argument. Consider the documentation.